# How to get Ids of inserted data in NPoco?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-core, npoco

I have a SQL script that when run, inserts rows in 2 tables. How can I access the Ids of newly inserted rows in Npoco. Here is what my SQL looks like:

```
DECLARE @@clientId TABLE (Id INT);

INSERT [dbo].[Clients] ([FirstName], [LastName])
OUTPUT INSERTED.clientId INTO @@clientId 
VALUES ( N'John', N'Doe');

SELECT Id FROM @@clientId;
```

How can I access the selected data in last line, in NPoco using C# ?

Answer (score 3):

It should auto updated in client object. I have worked in Nhibernate and EF. It should work for NPoco as well.

```
    public void AddClient(Client client)  
    {  
        connection.Insert<Client>(client);
        //after save client.Id.


    }
```

Comment: I am not using Insert method from NPoco as I have a custom script to run.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the script with NPoco?  Maybe something like this?

```
var RC = Database.Fetch<List<int>>(SQL);
```